# case switch and scope in js

Tags: javascript, scope, switch-statement

I'm looking for some help. I am not sure my speed, handling, acceleration values in the bottom method arguments are not being affected or using the update values that are being added to within the case-switch. I want speed to take the changes applied in the switch then the updated variable to be pushed in the methods below. I hope I'm making sense. My values always stay at 10

```
const addAttributes = (_element) => {let selectedElement = _element.layer;

    var speed = 10;
    var handling = 10;
    var acceleration = 10;
  
    switch (_element.layer.name) {
 
      case "1_grill":
        speed = speed + 100;
      
      case "Fiber1":
        handling = handling + 25;
        speed = speed + 25;

      case "yellow_headlights": // asset name without #
        acceleration = acceleration + 35;
    }
   
    attributesList.push({
        trait_type: "Handling",
        Value: handling,})

    attributesList.push({
        trait_type: "Speed",
        Value: speed,})
  
    attributesList.push({
        trait_type: "Acceleration",
        Value: acceleration,})
```

Comment: It would be nice to know how `_element` and `attributesList` are defined. BTW a `break` needs to be added at the end of each `case`, otherwise all `case`s will be considered.

Comment: I want each case to run if they are true.

Comment: Please make a [mcve] including the values that you are calling the function with

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because you'e _element.layer.name doesn't match any of the cases never. You should check that.

And you should put a [break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) after each case too.

Comment: I did I even printed to console to ensure.

Comment: Put more of the code on the question. Please.